# как сравнить 2 массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Имеются 2 массива объектов, как произвести строгое сравнение

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
  { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
  { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
],

[
  { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
  { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
  { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
],
```

Comment: посмотрите на библиотеку лодаш https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual

Comment: Берешь и производишь... перебором собственных свойств, естественно. В чем конкретно возникли трудности?

Answer (score 1):

Если нет вложенных структур, все значения примитивны и порядок объектов тоже должен совпадать, можно попробовать так:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
  { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
  { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
  { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
  { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
];

function isEqual(a1, a2) {
  if (a1.length !== a2.length) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
    const obj1 = a1[i];
    const obj2 = a2[i];

    if (Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) return false;

    for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(obj1)) {
      if (obj2[key1] !== value1) return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(isEqual(arr1, arr2));

console.log(isEqual(arr1, arr2.concat({})));

arr2[0].text = 'foo';
console.log(isEqual(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для массивов и базовых объектов (не для `Date`/`Set`/`Map`/`HTMLElement`/итд):

```js
const [arrayOne, arrayTwo] = getTestArrays();

// магия
const compareObj = (a, b) => {
  const aKeys = Object.keys(a);
  if (aKeys.length !== Object.keys(b).length) return 'различается количество свойств';
  let recResult;
  for (const key of aKeys) {
    if (!b.hasOwnProperty(key)) return 'отсутствует как минимум одно собственное свойство';
    if (typeof a[key] === 'object') {
      if (!+(recResult = compareObj(a[key], b[key]))) return recResult;
    } else {
      if (typeof a[key] !== typeof b[key]) return 'различаются типы значений как минимум одного свойства';
      if (a[key] !== b[key]) return 'различается как минимум одно значение';
    }
  }
  return true;
};

// тесты
console.log('1.', compareObj(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
arrayOne[3].name = String(arrayOne[3].name);
console.log('2.', compareObj(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
arrayOne[2].text = 'lalala';
console.log('3.', compareObj(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
delete arrayOne[1].text;
console.log('4.', compareObj(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
arrayOne[1].toString = 'omg!';
console.log('5.', compareObj(arrayOne, arrayTwo));


// просто чтобы вниз эти массивы спихнуть
function getTestArrays() {
  return [
    [
      { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
      { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
      { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
      { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
      { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
    ], [
      { id: 1, name: 1, text: 'test1' },
      { id: 2, name: 2, text: 'test2' },
      { id: 3, name: 3, text: 'test3' },
      { id: 4, name: 4, text: 'test4' },
      { id: 5, name: 5, text: 'test5' },
    ],
  ];
}
```